# How do I play all songs shuffled of an artist?

Tags: apple-music

I mean all songs of an artist that exists in Apple music.

The songs should include those that are not in my library.

I couldn't find a way on iOS or macOS.

Answer (score -2):

On macOS:

Open Music.app.

Click on the "Artists" tab in the sidebar.

Right-click on desired artist.

Click the option "Shuffle ".

(Monterey 12.3.1)